# Is it safe to uninstall an old version of Bitcoin-qt after having installed the latest one?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I´ve been using Bitcoin-qt (version 0.8.1.) for several weeks but lately I´ve had problems due to a so called "corrupted block database" issue, so I´ve decided to update my client to the latest version (0.8.5.).

It´s already installed (I just installed it on my laptop without removing the older version), synchronized and working properly.

Can I remove the older version of the client by clicking on the uninstall icon? 
Is it safe to do so? If so, do I have to backup my wallet.dat file again or the previous backup still works with the latest version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention the operating system, but talk about "clicking the uninstall icon" I am assuming that you are using Windows.

Making a backup of your *wallet.dat* before updates and at regular intervals is sensible. If you installed *bitcoin-qt 0.8.5* into the same directory as *bitcoin-qt 0.8.1*, uninstalling the older *bitcoin-qt 0.8.1* might break your new install. If they are in separate install directories I would expect it to be alright (just based on what I would consider expected behaviour, I don't have intimate knowledge of the behaviour of the Bitcoin-QT-Windows client).

If you added any new addresses in since you imported the wallet to *bitcoin-qt 0.8.5* you might have generated them after the last backup, so it would be prudent to create an additional backup of the newest *wallet.dat*.

Usually, I'd consider the following the correct order for an update (unless the software has its own update function):

1. backup
2. uninstall old
3. install new
4. import backup (by keeping the backup alive!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Murch. There´s something I don´t fully understand about the fourth step you´ve mentioned. What do you mean exactly? How do I import backup?

Comment: In the beginning you have Bitcoin-QT in Folder *A*. You create a backup in *A-Backup*. Now there is two options: If you can just update Bitcoin-QT, you can do that and are finished. If you have to uninstall and re-install, you should uninstall the old version first, then install the new Bitcoin-QT in e.g. folder *B*, finally you **copy** your wallet from *A-Backup* to the location of the wallet that was created with the new installation. That way you still have a backup in *A-Backup* but you can access the funds that you had before the update.